# Resample error: ValueError: month must be in 1..12

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv file that I would like to resample at 1 minute granularity.

I do this in the following way:

```
main  = pd.read_csv(pump, 
                    skiprows=12, 
                    index_col='Timestamp',
                    parse_dates=True
                    )

main = main.resample('1Min', how='max')
```

But I get the following error:

> ValueError: month must be in 1..12

I got confused, because when I print main to see how it looks like, the time stamp is in the following format:

Timestamp
2014-04-15 00:00:00

Comment: Just what it says: you try to create a date from incorrect input. The traceback should tell you where this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

With little information to go on, but a decent amount of experience working with dates in programming, I would guess that you likely have one of two problems:

1. Your data is bad and you are going to have to find out where your month is out of bounds.
2. Your timestamp format needs to be specified when you parse it. Your program is reading 2014 and trying turn it into a month.

infer_datetime_format : boolean, default False
If True and parse_dates is enabled for a column, attempt to infer the datetime format to speed up the processing

Since you believe you have eliminated both of the above possibilities, maybe this will help. All of the examples I see for this function have this format for max in how:

```
ts.resample('1Min', how=np.max)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm very new to python so I have zero experience. How do I specify the timestamp format? I checked the data and it seems to me that the month is not out of bounds.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling Try using the intialization part of the documentation examples with your resample method. Print their data after it is initialized and compare it to yours for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass that particular column in below function and change date,month&year order.

```
def changedate_formate(df):
split = df.split('.')
a = split[1]
b = split[2]
c = split[0]

return ''.join(a+b+c)
```